# Ajax call not sending any data when added image data using django ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to send data from a popup form through django template which includes an image also, when tried to access data in console. Data is properly visible. But when ajax function used, no data is received in 'request.POST' in django view. But when image file is removed from AJAX data data is recieved properly

HTML code:

```
<div class="form-popup-custom col-lg-12" id="myForm" data-method="POST">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/action_page.php" class="form-container" method="post">
      <div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h5 style="font-size:22px;">Total Amount Selected :</h5>
        <h5 style="font-size:20px;" id="amount_text">0.0</h5>
    </div>
</div>

    <input type="hidden" id="amount_text">

      <label for="utr" style="
      margin-bottom: 2vw;
    margin-left: 3vw;
"><b>Enter UTR number</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="utr" maxlength="22" minlength="16" placeholder="Enter UTR number" name="UTR" required>

      <label for="utr"><b>Enter Amount</b></label>
    <input type="number" id="amt" placeholder="Enter UTR number" name="amt" required>
        <div class="header" id="myHeader" style="
    margin-top: 2vw;
">
      <label for="enter-amount"><b>Upload UTR slip</b></label>
      <input type="file" id="slip" placeholder="select file" name="select_file" required>
        </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>


</center>





<div class="col-lg-12 text-center" style="
    text-align: center;
">

    <input type="submit" id="sbt_btn" onclick="submit()" value="Submit">
    </div>
```

Ajax call:

```
    function submit() {
      console.log("isme aa gyaa!!!!!!");
    order_ids=Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name=_selected_action]:checked").each(function(){
    order_ids.push($(this).val());
    });

    var amount = document.getElementById('amount_text').innerHTML;
    var utr = document.getElementById("utr").value;
    var amt = document.getElementById('amt').value;
    var errorflag = false;
    files_=Array();
    var files = document.getElementById("slip").files[0];
    files_.push(files);

    {#var remark = document.getElementById('request_remark').value;#}

    if(order_ids.length <= 0){
        alert("Please select orders.");
    }
        url = '/api/admin-apis/money_deposit_request/';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data: {'orders': order_ids, 'amount': amount, 'remark': 'remark', 'utr': utr, 'amt': amt, 'fd':files_},
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.status == 0) {
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                    returdatn;
                } else {
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                }

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                alert("Done");

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Data entered not correct");
            }

        });
    }
```

When it is being run with files_ with file in it, request returns empty querydict.
I'm stuck in this since too long, any sort of help will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but your files are supposed to be in request.FILES, not in request.POST.

Comment: whole request dict is empty.

Comment: I see, then you may try to set contentType: false.